# Calculating toal number of feet climbed by Elevation giving weird results

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, elevation

I am calculating total number of feet climbed when user walking. I am using below core-location delegate method.

I declared oldelevation,newelevation and Totalelevation as int.

First Time I am taking Current spot Elevation to oldelevation.

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
   newelevation =[location altitude]; //  Present Elevation

   if (newelevation > oldelevation) {

        TotalElevation = TotalElevation + newelevation - oldelevation;

       }

   oldelevation=newelevation;// Storing current elevation in old elevation.

}
```

Finally At the end of walk I multiplied Totalelevation with 3.28084 to get total number of feet climbed.

I am comparing my  results with **Runtastic** Application.

I walked 0.40 Miles, Where Runtastic is 16 feet and my app total number of feet climbed is 208 feet.

I referred the following links but those are not giving accurate results.

[Calculating Cumulative elevation gain give me wierd results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210248/calculating-cumulative-elevation-gain-give-me-wierd-results)

[How to calculate elevation like in runkeeper application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156415/how-to-calculate-elevation-like-in-runkeeper-application)

[iPhone Core Location: Calculate total elevation loss/gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928698/iphone-core-location-calculate-total-elevation-loss-gain)

Comment: Are you trying to calculate total number of feet climbed during the walk, or the gain in elevation from the beginning of the walk to the end?

Comment: @CarlVeazey is there any difference in total number of feet climbed and gain in elevation.could you help me please.

Comment: if you walk up a hundred foot hill and back down, you'll have climbed 100 feet and gained 0 feet in elevation, right?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Yes you are right. I edited my question I want total number of feet climbed.

Answer (score 1):

You should always evaluate the the altitude accuracy before doing calculation. the property verticalAccuracy returns negative if the altitude is invalid

```
if (currentLocation.verticalAccuracy >= 0 && previewsLocation.verticalAccuracy >=0) {
   if (currentLocation.altitude > previewsLocation.altitude) {
      TotalElevation = TotalElevation + currentLocation.altitude - previewsLocation.altitude;
   }
}
```

Comment: I used above condition but there is no effect. I am getting very high values of climbed feet.

Comment: remember to initialize oldelevation to DBL_MAX. so the first location is ignored

Comment: Yes. I am adding current spot elevation to oldelevation so the first location will be ignored.